can one cover a short position in common shares by holding a long position in (convertible) preferred shares?
EDIT: I phrased this question ambiguously.  The answer I've accepted suggests that the practice is probably legal in the US.  I'd like to know whether any North American brokerages allow it in practice, so I've posted a followup question.

This question is about the practices of brokerages in the United States and Canada, as constrained by law, and about stocks traded on exchanges in those countries (e.g. NYSE).
Question:

Is it possible to cover a short position in common stock by holding an offsetting long position in preferred stock, where the preferred stock is convertible on demand to the held amount of common stock?

Explanation.
Various regulations (such as Regulation T in the United States) stipulate that when an account holds a short position in a stock, the account must also hold some offsetting asset so that the short position can be covered if necessary.
Many publicly traded companies offer so-called preferred shares of stock that are, among other things, convertible into common (i.e., ordinary) shares of the company's stock at some fixed ratio.  For example, each share of preferred stock may be convertible to 100 shares of common stock.
Under what circumstances (if any) it is possible to use a long position in preferred stock to cover a short position in common stock?  For example, suppose each preferred stock is convertible to 100 common stock.  Are there brokerages that allow one to hold 100 common stock short, while holding 1 preferred stock long to cover the short position?
This would seem to meet the intention of the coverage requirements: in the event that the short position is called, the preferred stock could be converted to 100 shares of common stock to satisfy the call (or just sold, as the preferred stock would generally be worth at least 100 times the common stock).  However, from my limited understanding of Regulation T, this doesn't seem possible in the United States. But I am not sure.

Is your question implying a need to hold a long position of the same shares you are shorting? Regulation T requires only that you have total collateral up to the margin requirement amounts; that collateral could be in the form of cash or other unrelated securities. Ultimately if you short a stock and then purchase shares where at least some value comes from the ability to convert into a long position of the same stock, you likely have offset a large part of the potential gains (and losses) from having the short position in the first place.

Not the same shares, no.  Holding common shares short, and preferred shares long to cover.  Preferred shares are distinct from common shares, but can be converted into common shares on request of the holder.  Some readings of Regulation T say that %150, not %100, of the short position must be covered, but per D Stanley's answer below it may be that %100 suffices if the covering asset is convertible to the shorted one.

Not my area of expertise, but according Part 220.12  it appears so, as long as the conversion can be done within 90 days (i.e. the holder can voluntarily convert, akin to exercising an American-style option)

The required margin for each security position held in a margin account shall be as follows:
...
(c) Short sale of a nonexempted security, except for a non-equity security:

(1) 150 percent of the current market value of the security; or
(2) 100 percent of the current market value if a security exchangeable or convertible within 90 calendar days without restriction other than the payment of money into the security sold short is held in the account, provided that any long call to be used as margin in connection with a short sale of the underlying security is an American-style option issued by a registered clearing corporation and listed or traded on a registered national securities exchange with an exercise price that does not exceed the price at which the underlying security was sold short.


Keep in mind, however, that like an American call option, the conversion of a preferred security to cover margin calls may be a bad financial transaction, meaning the stock that you get as a result of the conversion may be worth much less than the preferred stock that is converted.

Thank you.  (i)  Concerning the requirement "provided that any long call to be used .... is an American-style option...", does this mean that the long security has to be an option (as opposed to a stock)?  Or does that restriction only apply if the long security is specifically a call?   (ii) I am interested in doing this in practice, so in addition to legality, I need to find a broker that will do it.   So legality would be useful to know, but I'd also like to know what brokers will actually do.

I interpret that requirement as only applying to options, meaning you can't use a european-style option because it cannot be exercised before it matures

As to whether brokers will let a convertible preferred be used as margin collateral, I have no idea. You would need to ask your broker

Thanks.  (So far I've asked my brokers and a few others and all have said no.)

The margin requirement for a short sale is the proceeds from the sale plus and additional 50% for a total of 150% (brokers can require more).
Back in the day, a convertible preferred stock could be used as a substitute for 100 shares (same issuer) for covering a short call. I don't know if that's still the case today.

Thanks.  I think the 50% you mention is in addition to the proceeds from the short, so in that sense is 150% total.  And the question seems to be whether this requirement reduces to 100% if the covering asset is directly convertible to the shorted stock, and (if the law does allow that) whether any US or Canadian brokerages will in fact allow it.  The brokerages I have contacted so far say they don't.

It's highly unlikely that a discount broker would allow this.  A full service broker would likely be the only one that would.  This was allowed 30+ years ago. In general, it's a different world now.
